# I want to display as "Please Select" in Spinner before selecting a value. After selecting a value it should disappear

Tags: android, spinner

I'm using Spinner to select a value from the drop down menu. I want initially to be displayed as "Please Select", after selecting a value it should disappear. I'm using the following code,

```
UPanelID = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, data);
dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
UPanelID.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
UPanelID.setOnItemSelectedListener(typeSelectedListener);
```

> data is a String array

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by setting  `android:prompt="Please Select"` attribute  in `Spinner` in your xml file.

Or, you can see following example for making the first item in the Spinner `"Please Select"`:

http://b2creativedesigns.comuv.com/Spinner.html

Answer (score 1):

Here I am just adding the Please Select to the new array. This may be helpful to you

```
    String[] newarr= new String[data.length+1];
    newarr[0] = "Please select";
    for(int i=1;i<newarr.length;i++)
    {
        newarr[i] = data[i-1];
    }
    UPanelID = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, newarr);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    UPanelID.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    UPanelID.setOnItemSelectedListener(typeSelectedListener);
```

Comment: After selecting an value it should be removed from the list. I hope this is not an correct way.

Comment: ok.after selecting the value then you can set adapter to the spinner again.

Comment: but why to display like this. if user doesn't want to set spinner again. there must be select at top right